# Pegar o valor de uma string dentro de uma variavel PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html5

```
$a = " A=1 B=2";
```

Preciso usar `echo` em `$a` e exibir o valor de B. Não quero usar array. É porque eu vou criar uma coluna no banco de dados aonde ela vai abrigar todas as opções ativas. E não quero ter o trabalho de criar mais de 10 colunas só pra opções. Então ficaria assim, o valor da COLUNA `opcoes` irá ter *option1=true* option2=false ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php), mas teria que fazer `replace` de espaços em branco para `&`:

```
<?php
$a = " A=1 B=2";
$a = str_replace(' ','&',$a);
parse_str($a, $valor);
echo $valor['B'];
?>
```

Veja no **[Ideone](https://ideone.com/5eXxg3)**.

Comment: Perfeito cara !

Answer (score 1):

A resposta do @dvd funciona corretamente. Mas há uma outra abordagem que pode ser utilizada com arrays. Você pode usar a função [serialize](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.serialize.php) para converter de array para string (e salvar no banco) e a unserialize para converter de string para array. A vantagem disso é que você poderá liberar o uso da virgula sem ter que fazer escape nas suas opções.

Um exemplo disso seria:

```
//dados vindos do formulario
$opcoes = $_POST;

//opções seria algo equivalente 
//a ['opcao1'=>'valor 1', 'opcao 2' => valor2]
$opcoes = serialize($opcoes);//$opcoes agora é uma string

//então salve no banco

//e depois que você ler o campo do banco deserialize assim
$opcoes = $campoLidoDoBanco;//$opcoes é uma string
$opcoes = unserialize($opcoes);//$opcoes agora é um array
```